# VBA: concatenate strings and retain format

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code, part of a loop, to concatenate strings. What I found is that the format is not retained. In one of the cells, some letters are in red color. The color, after concatenation, is no longer there. I can't just copy the cell, which would retain the format, because I have about 10 cell worth of content to concatenate into one string. Google search on the subject turns up nothing. I guess I could write code to, after concatenation, find the letters and change their color but wonder if there is another way of doing it.

```
temp_string = temp_string & IIf(Len(Trim(found.Offset(0, 10))) <> 0, Chr(10) & found.Offset(0, 10), "")
```

Comment: I believe your only option is to update the colours (via the Characters object) after the concatenation.

Comment: *wonder if there is another way of doing it.* No. You have to do exactly as you said, after concatenation, find the letters and change their color

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late hit. :) I had the same problem where I wanted to retain the source formatting when setting a cell equal to the result of a formula, rather than copy/pasting. What I ended up doing is just nesting the action in a copy/paste of the format.

```
Range([applicable range]).Copy
[code inserting the result of the formula into the applicable range]
Range([applicable range]).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```